# SoX Error While Merging Multiple Audio files

Tags: linux, audio, sox

I am trying to merge a folder full of wav files with the command `sox *.wav combined.wav` and am getting this error:

```
sox formats: no handler for detected file type `inode/x-empty; charset=binary'
```

I Googled the error and cannot find any solutions. Can anyone describe how to fix this error, or what flags to add to `sox` while running the command? Thanks. Here is the wav files I am trying to combine:

```
10-51-52-0025.raw.wav  11-06-29-0030.raw.wav  11-16-29-0536.raw.wav
10-52-52-0062.raw.wav  11-07-29-0085.raw.wav  11-17-29-0749.raw.wav
10-58-28-0559.raw.wav  11-08-29-0135.raw.wav  11-18-29-0812.raw.wav
10-59-28-0655.raw.wav  11-09-29-0192.raw.wav  11-19-29-0909.raw.wav
11-00-28-0696.raw.wav  11-10-29-0242.raw.wav  11-27-07-0658.raw.wav
11-01-28-0744.raw.wav  11-11-29-0298.raw.wav  11-28-07-0731.raw.wav
11-02-28-0828.raw.wav  11-12-29-0348.raw.wav  11-29-07-0779.raw.wav
11-03-28-0876.raw.wav  11-13-29-0432.raw.wav  11-30-07-0834.raw.wav
11-04-28-0941.raw.wav  11-14-29-0483.raw.wav
11-05-28-0989.raw.wav  11-15-29-0508.raw.wav
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to you use ffmpeg.

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i <(printf "file '$PWD/%s'\n" ./*.wav) -c copy output.wav
```

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate

Comment: The above code won't work  if any filenames contain apostrophes. This is because they need to get escaped in the input file.

Answer (score 0):

From http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html :

> To determine the format of an input file, SoX will use, in order of
>   precedence and as given or available:
>
> 1. Command-line format options.
> 2. The contents of the file header.
> 3. The filename extension.

So if you are sure the files are of the WAVE format, you could try adding `-t wav`:

```
sox -t wav *.wav combined.wav
```

If the files are in fact of raw file format or they are missing information like bit depth (`-b`) and rate (`-r`), you will have to provide these parameters as well. More info on that in [Converting RAW audio data to WAV with scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059014/converting-raw-audio-data-to-wav-with-scripting).